# I accidentally delete the import/export Profile on Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I accidentally delete the import and export Profile on Magento, I want to know that without only create new on. It can restore back or not ? And if I must create new of both, it will automatically connect to the sql ?

Thank you.

---

Update:

I already got the strategy to test, and it work on the same setting. But if anyone have anything to advise me or let me know I appreciate for you kind, Thank you.